# Can I create/declare several PowerShell Objects of the same type at once?

Tags: powershell

I have a PowerShell (version 5.1) form with various sets of `System.Windows.Forms` Objects in it all named something generic, like `$label1`, `$label2`, etc. as well as `$textBox1`, `$textBox2`, etc.

Currently, I'm creating them each as they appear in the Form, like so:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

$Form = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form | ForEach-Object {
    $_.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(800,550)
    $_.StartPosition = 'CenterScreen'
    $_.Text = "Example Form Name"
    $_.Topmost = $true
}

$label1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$label1 | ForEach-Object {
    $_.Location = '10,10'
    $_.Size = '156,20'
    $_.Text = 'Dummy text part 1'
}

$textBox1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$textBox1 | ForEach-Object {
    $_.Location = '166,8'
    $_.Size = '100,20'
}

$label2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$label2 | ForEach-Object {
    $_.Location = '267, 10'
    $_.Size = '85,20'
    $_.Text = 'Dummy text part 2'
}

$textBox2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$textBox2 | ForEach-Object {
    $_.Location = '352,8'
    $_.Size = '100,20'
}

#A lot more lines of similar code go here

$Form.Controls.Add($label1)
$Form.Controls.Add($textBox1)
$Form.Controls.Add($label2)
$Form.Controls.Add($textBox2)

$result = $Form.ShowDialog()
```

I've got a few dozen of these Objects that I am creating and naming according to this scheme, and I'd really like to save some lines by creating all of these on one line each (e.g. all the `label`s on one line, then all the `textBox`es on one line), or at least in one method/function each.

I tried this:

```
$label1, $label2, $label3 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
```

instead of declaring each `$label` on its own line in the full demo form above, but PowerShell doesn't seem to work like that; it only creates `$label1` (which itself is odd; I would've expected it to only create `$label3` were it going to work on only one of them) and PowerShell ISE throws an error for the property declarations later on for `$label2` and `$label3`:

```
The property 'Location' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set. 
At <filepath>.ps1:43 char:5
+     $_.Location = '267, 10'
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFound
```

...and so on.

Is there a way I can create multiple of the same type of Object with an incrementing suffix all in one go, instead of declaring them each on their own line, or am I stuck writing these how I've currently got them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Multiple assignment assigns the elements of an array on the right hand of the assignment to the variables on the left hand. `New-Object` in and of itself does not allow for creating multiple objects at once. You could write a loop or a function that produces an array of labels and then use multiple assignment for assigning the elements of that array to the variables.

```
$label1, $label2, $label3 = 1..3 | ForEach-Object {
    New-Object Windows.Forms.Label
}
```

or

```
function New-Label {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [int]$Count = 1
    )

    for ($i=0; $i -lt $count; $i++) {
        New-Object Windows.Forms.Label
    }
}

$label1, $label2, $label3 = New-Label 3
```

However, I think a better approach would be to write a function for creating one label object with the given parameters, and then assign the output of that function to one variable.

```
function New-Label {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$Location,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$Size,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [string]$Text = ''
    )

    $o = New-Object Windows.Forms.Label
    $o.Location = $Location
    $o.Size     = $Size
    $o.Text     = $Text

    return $o
}

$label1 = New-Label -Location '10,10' -Size '156,20' -Text 'Dummy text part 1'
$label2 = New-Label -Location '267,10' -Size '85,20' -Text 'Dummy text part 2'
$label3 = ...
```

You could also directly add the labels to the form instead of assigning them to variables first:

```
$Form.Controls.Add((New-Label '10,10' '156,20' 'Dummy text part 1'))
$Form.Controls.Add((New-Label '267,10' '85,20' 'Dummy text part 2'))
$Form.Controls.Add((New-Label ...))
```

Note that you need grouping expressions around the function calls when matrjoshking (nesting) them into the method calls. Hence the two sets of parentheses.

Of course, `New-Label` could be improved further, e.g. by having integer arrays instead of strings for `$Location` and `$Size`. Or by having another parameter set with individual values for `$Top`, `$Left`, `$Width`, and `$Height`, and assigning the values depending on which parameter set is used. Parameters should be validated too. And so on, and so forth.

Comment: Matrjoschka/Matryoschka is an interesting word to be verbed.

Comment: I've gone with a combination of your "better" approach in combination with the direct addition of the labels to the form. It should be noted though that the way your direct label addition lines are written requires the preceding "better" approach code (as it references `New-Label`, declared in the aforementioned `function New-Label {}`).

Answer (score 1):

This...

```
$label1, $label2, $label3 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
```

...creates a new `Label` and assigns it to `$label1`.  Nothing is assigned to `$label2` and `$label3` because there are no more values on the right side to assign to them.  If that syntax did assign all three variables they would (likely) all contain the same `Label` instance, which wouldn't work for your use case, anyways.

Instead, to instantiate three `Label` instances and assign them to the three variables you'd need to do this...

```
$label1, $label2, $label3 = (New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label), (New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label), (New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label)
```

...which can be simplified to...

```
$label1, $label2, $label3 = 1..3 | ForEach-Object -Process { New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label }
```

...which can be simplified to...

```
$label1, $label2, $label3 = 1..3 | % { New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label }
```

Comment: That code comes straight from the question.  It doesn't throw an error on my system, PowerShell v5.1.17763.316 on Windows 10.  `$x, $y, $z = 1..2` doesn't throw an error, either, with each variable containing (or not containing) the expected value.

Comment: @BACON I should note I'm running the code (Ansgar may be as well) in PowerShell ISE. VS Code or PowerShell.exe may not show the error; I haven't checked. ISE will throw the error and still run the form.

Comment: @TylerH Yes, I am just using `PowerShell.exe`.  However, you did not indicate you get that error in your question, either?  The error you do get (`The property 'Location' cannot be found on this object.`) when attempting to operate on `$label2` and `$label3` is because neither has an object reference.

Comment: @BACON The error I mentioned in the question is from when I run the whole form script with `$label1, $label2, $label3 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label` instead of individually declaring them. I'll clarify the question, but FWIW I do think your answer already covers what Ansgar's comment mentions (then again I'm the one asking the question here so I'm not necessarily the best judge...)